# HTML <p> tags not changing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

so I am making a project to solve triangles based on user input. I am using the Chrome Dev Editor in order to make it a Chrome app. I am having trouble getting my code to work though. Right now, I am testing it to see if it will change a paragraph when a button is clicked. Here is the piece causing me trouble:

```
function degToRad(num) {
  if (num === undefined) { return; }
  return Math.PI * num / 180;
}


function init() {
  var text = document.querySelector("#form1");
  sideA = text.elements[0].value;
  sideB = text.elements[1].value;
  sideC = text.elements[2].value;
  angleA = degToRad(text.elements[3].value);
  angleB = degToRad(text.elements[4].value);
  angleC = degToRad(text.elements[5].value);
  whatWeGot();
}

//determine which algorithm to go to and run it
function whatWeGot() {
  if (angleA === undefined && angleB === undefined && angleC === undefined) {
    algSSS();
  } else if (sideC === undefined && angleB === undefined && angleC === undefined) {
    algSSA();
  } else if (sideB === undefined && sideC === undefined) {
    if (angleC === undefined) { angleC = Math.PI - (angleA + angleB); }
    else if (angleB === undefined) { angleB = Math.PI - (angleA + angleB); }
    else { angleA = Math.PI - (angleB + angleC); }
    algASA();
  }
}

function algSSS() {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'sss worked';
}
```

Here is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>TrigCalc</title>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="greeting"></div>
  <p id="prompt1">Fill up sides A, B, then C, angles in degrees <strong>(Warning: does not test for amibiguous case)</strong></p>
  <form id="form1" action="form_action.asp">
    Side A:  <input type="Number" name="sideA"><br>
    Side B:  <input type="Number" name="sideC"><br>
    Side C:  <input type="Number" name="sideC"><br>
    Angle A:  <input type="Number" name="angleA"><br>
    Angle B:  <input type="Number" name="angleB"><br>
    Angle C:  <input type="Number" name="angleC"><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="init()" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
  <p id='test'></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Other things are posted in the manifest.json file which creates the Chrome App window and gives it other properties. Would it be better to use JQuery for this sort of thing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "logic" of if's and else's is not so organized,

It is not so clear what you want to do.
The html injection into the < p > does work as you can see here -     [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fo3hcn4/)

```
function whatWeGot() {
     document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'sss worked';

  if (angleA === undefined && angleB === undefined && angleC === undefined)  
    ....
```

The angleA === undefined etc.. you should replace it with something like angleA !=0 or !(angleA & angleB & angleC >0) -->

[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/2fo3hcn4/4/)

Also, Chrome as a nice debugger utility (F12) you can use it to see the value of your variables.

As for jQuery - it is a great and very recommended tool. It will be a little easier to do what you did with jQuery but for more complicated things jQuery saves A LOT. Must to know tool.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in algSSS, problem is that if input field is empty then angleX = 0.

So basically instead of

```
if (angleA === undefined ...)
```

you want

```
if (angleA == 0 ...)
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdZPVv?editors=101)